# Handling Two, three,four finger swipe in android

Tags: android, multi-touch, touch-event, gestures, onfling

I am trying to implement 2,3 and 4 finger swipe (right to left swipe,left to right swipe,top to bottom swipe and bottom to top swipe) in android.

I tried to achieve this functionality in `onFling` method of `SimpleOnGestureListener` and `onTouchEvent()` method in view but i was not able to do this.

Please help me to achieve this functionality.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Mind posting some code as to what you have actually tried?

Comment: i tried the example which is explained in this url [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796114/2-finger-swipe-in-android?rq=1) but it is not working as expected and also it is not consistent.